# Which auto generated picturebox was clicked? VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code. Im trying to find out which of the 64 pictureboxes was clicked:

```
        For i As Integer = 1 To 8
        For j As Integer = 1 To 8
            SpilleBræt(i, j) = New PictureBox 'Opretter picturebox
            If (i + j) Mod 2 = 1 Then
                Me.SpilleBræt(i, j).BackgroundImage = Skak.My.Resources.DarkTile
            Else
                Me.SpilleBræt(i, j).BackgroundImage = Skak.My.Resources.LightTile
            End If

            'Placering, størrelse, m.v.
            Me.SpilleBræt(i, j).Location = New System.Drawing.Point((i - 1) * 103, (j - 1) * 103)
            Me.SpilleBræt(i, j).Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 100)
            Me.SpilleBræt(i, j).Name = "SpilleBrik" & i & j
            Me.PanelSpilleBræt.Controls.Add(Me.SpilleBræt(i, j))
        Next j
    Next i
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you add a click handler to your `PictureBox` controls?

Comment: Im not sure what that is exactly :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to handle a click event, the first thing you'll need is a click handler.  Could be something as simple as this:

```
Private Sub PictureBox_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)  
    ' Do something in here
End Sub
```

When you create your `PictureBox` controls, bind the handler to their click event:

```
AddHandler Me.SpilleBræt(i, j).Click, AddressOf PictureBox_Click
Me.PanelSpilleBræt.Controls.Add(Me.SpilleBræt(i, j))
```

What this should do is invoke the `PictureBox_Click` method any time the user clicks on the `PictureBox`.  Within that method, `sender` is the element which was clicked:

```
Private Sub PictureBox_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)  
    Dim clickedBox As PictureBox
    clickedBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
    ' clickedBox is the element which was clicked
End Sub
```

Comment: Great it works. 
You mentioned that 'sender' is the clicked element. But how do i then change the background of the selected picbox. Could i go "clickedBox = *path to image*"?

Comment: @JonasBernhøft: Try setting any property you like on `clickedBox`, such as the `BackgroundImage` property.